# Connect to linux outside network without port forwarding

Tags: ubuntu, samba, home-server, ubuntu-server, ports

Currently I am running Lubuntu 19.04. Right now I am using samba to share my files on my local network ( anyone connected to my network can access the files )

Is there a way to access my files from another network but using a GUI like file explorer, so that I can also view the files and then download them if needed.

I am willing to do anything to access my files from another networking. The only thing is I don't have access to my router and I can't do port forwarding.

Can anyone help??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TeamViewer](https://teamviewer.com) to access your desktop and files from anywhere.  It is available for [Linux](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/).  It works through firewalls, as both the client and the server portions connect to the TeamViewer service, not to each other.  TeamViewer is free for personal use.

Comment: Thanks I will try that, but are they any other options, maybe something similar to the way you access files from a NAS drives

Comment: @Ammar No.  Its similar to VNC and Remote Desktop, but has the capability of transferring files.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer you're working from (so not the file-server) can have a known IP address, you could try to build a reverse tunnel with ssh from the file-server box.

I'm doing the same with a tiny (remote) server which is connected with internet through a GSM modem (no known IP). This box automatically creates a reverse ssh-tunnel to a dyndns domian (my home computer). On my home computer I can access the remote box, transfer files, ssh, etc.